# vue with typescript method testing using jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a vue component like below

## person.vue

```
export default class Person extends Vue{

errors = [];

Person(){
super();
}

validatePersonInfo(personName){

if(!personName){

 this.errors.push('please enter student details');
}

}
```

I am trying to test validatePersonInfo method using jest like below,

```
jest.mock('@/pages/person.vue');
  
  describe('Person TestSuite', () => {
    let personObj: any;
    beforeEach(() => {
      personObj = new Person();
    });

    it('test validatePersonInfo', () => {
    jest.spyOn(personObj, 'validatePersonInfo').mockReturnValue(() => undefined);
  });
```

Tests are passed but its gives me an error like below and also this method is not covered in unit coverage report.
console.error [Vue warn]: data functions should return an object:

Comment: You didn't show how it's actually used tested. As for a mock, it's wrong. You mocked it to return a function. It should be either `mockImplementation(() => undefined)` or `mockReturnValue(undefined)`. not in between.

Comment: I used mockImplementation.  But still its not covered. Any example for the above code will be helpful for me.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem.You didn't show the component and the test. It's unclear how `validatePersonInfo` and `errors` are used. It's unknown why the warning is there. Usually Vue components are tested as such and not instantiated manually with `new`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. let me try out.